# ipsec tunnel blocks google services

Tags: linux, windows, ipsec, strongswan

I set up a strongswan responder on debian in GCE. I can connect to it via the strongswan app on android. No problems. 
I can also connect using the native vpn client in Windows 10. And when I do, the responder becomes my default gateway. (The whole point of this operation.). I can access most of the internet this way but no google services. No search engine, no gmail, youtube etc. pp.
A website that is running in GCE is also accessible. That site wants google fonts to be loaded. That fails.

Anybody have an idea why this is happening?

/etc/ipsec.conf:

```
    config setup
    charondebug="ike 1, knl 1, cfg 0"
    uniqueids=never

conn AndroidCon
    auto=add
    compress=no
    type=tunnel
    keyexchange=ikev2
    fragmentation=yes
    forceencaps=yes
    ike=aes128-sha256-ecp256,aes256-sha384-ecp384,aes128-sha256-modp2048,aes128-sha1-modp2048,aes256-sha384-modp4096,aes256-sha256-modp4096,aes256-sha1-mo$
    esp=aes128gcm16-ecp256,aes256gcm16-ecp384,aes128-sha256-ecp256,aes256-sha384-ecp384,aes128-sha256-modp2048,aes128-sha1-modp2048,aes256-sha384-modp4096$
    dpdaction=clear
    dpddelay=300s
    rekey=no
    left=%any
    leftid=%defaultroute
    leftcert=/etc/ipsec.d/certs/cert.pem
    leftsendcert=always
    leftsubnet=0.0.0.0/0
    right=%any
    rightid=%any
    rightauth=eap-mschapv2
    rightdns=8.8.8.8,8.8.4.4
    rightsourceip=172.31.0.0/24
    rightsendcert=never
    eap_identity=%identity
```

Server log when window connects:

```
    Jul 16 07:22:03 vpn-gateway ipsec[2578]: 07[NET] received packet: from x.x.x.x[15246] to 10.0.0.2[500] (384 bytes)
Jul 16 07:22:03 vpn-gateway ipsec[2578]: 07[ENC] parsed IKE_SA_INIT request 0 [ SA KE No N(FRAG_SUP) N(NATD_S_IP) N(NATD_D_IP) V V V V ]
Jul 16 07:22:03 vpn-gateway ipsec[2578]: 07[IKE] received MS NT5 ISAKMPOAKLEY v9 vendor ID
Jul 16 07:22:03 vpn-gateway ipsec[2578]: 07[IKE] received MS-Negotiation Discovery Capable vendor ID
Jul 16 07:22:03 vpn-gateway ipsec[2578]: 07[IKE] received Vid-Initial-Contact vendor ID
Jul 16 07:22:03 vpn-gateway ipsec[2578]: 07[ENC] received unknown vendor ID: 01:52:8b:bb:c0:06:96:12:18:49:ab:9a:1c:5b:2a:51:00:00:00:02
Jul 16 07:22:03 vpn-gateway ipsec[2578]: 07[IKE] x.x.x.x is initiating an IKE_SA
Jul 16 07:22:03 vpn-gateway ipsec[2578]: 07[IKE] local host is behind NAT, sending keep alives
Jul 16 07:22:03 vpn-gateway ipsec[2578]: 07[IKE] remote host is behind NAT
Jul 16 07:22:03 vpn-gateway ipsec[2578]: 07[ENC] generating IKE_SA_INIT response 0 [ SA KE No N(NATD_S_IP) N(NATD_D_IP) N(FRAG_SUP) N(MULT_AUTH) ]
Jul 16 07:22:03 vpn-gateway ipsec[2578]: 07[NET] sending packet: from 10.0.0.2[500] to x.x.x.x[15246] (288 bytes)
Jul 16 07:22:03 vpn-gateway ipsec[2578]: 08[NET] received packet: from x.x.x.x[6511] to 10.0.0.2[4500] (580 bytes)
Jul 16 07:22:03 vpn-gateway ipsec[2578]: 08[ENC] parsed IKE_AUTH request 1 [ EF(1/3) ]
Jul 16 07:22:03 vpn-gateway ipsec[2578]: 08[ENC] received fragment #1 of 3, waiting for complete IKE message
Jul 16 07:22:03 vpn-gateway ipsec[2578]: 05[NET] received packet: from x.x.x.x[6511] to 10.0.0.2[4500] (580 bytes)
Jul 16 07:22:03 vpn-gateway ipsec[2578]: 05[ENC] parsed IKE_AUTH request 1 [ EF(2/3) ]
Jul 16 07:22:03 vpn-gateway ipsec[2578]: 05[ENC] received fragment #2 of 3, waiting for complete IKE message
Jul 16 07:22:03 vpn-gateway ipsec[2578]: 06[NET] received packet: from x.x.x.x[6511] to 10.0.0.2[4500] (132 bytes)
Jul 16 07:22:03 vpn-gateway ipsec[2578]: 06[ENC] parsed IKE_AUTH request 1 [ EF(3/3) ]
Jul 16 07:22:03 vpn-gateway ipsec[2578]: 06[ENC] received fragment #3 of 3, reassembling fragmented IKE message
Jul 16 07:22:03 vpn-gateway charon: 06[ENC] parsed IKE_AUTH request 5 [ AUTH ]
Jul 16 07:22:03 vpn-gateway ipsec[2578]: 06[ENC] parsed IKE_AUTH request 1 [ IDi CERTREQ N(MOBIKE_SUP) CPRQ(ADDR DNS NBNS SRV ADDR6 DNS6 SRV6) SA TSi TSr ]
Jul 16 07:22:03 vpn-gateway ipsec[2578]: 06[IKE] received 41 cert requests for an unknown ca
Jul 16 07:22:03 vpn-gateway ipsec[2578]: 06[IKE] initiating EAP_IDENTITY method (id 0x00)
Jul 16 07:22:03 vpn-gateway ipsec[2578]: 06[IKE] peer supports MOBIKE
Jul 16 07:22:03 vpn-gateway ipsec[2578]: 06[IKE] authentication of 'CN=ipsec.xxx.xxx' (myself) with RSA signature successful
Jul 16 07:22:03 vpn-gateway ipsec[2578]: 06[IKE] sending end entity cert "CN=ipsec.xxx.xxx"
Jul 16 07:22:03 vpn-gateway ipsec[2578]: 06[IKE] sending issuer cert "C=US, O=Let's Encrypt, CN=Let's Encrypt Authority X3"
Jul 16 07:22:03 vpn-gateway ipsec[2578]: 06[ENC] generating IKE_AUTH response 1 [ IDr CERT CERT AUTH EAP/REQ/ID ]
Jul 16 07:22:03 vpn-gateway ipsec[2578]: 06[ENC] splitting IKE message with length of 3136 bytes into 3 fragments
Jul 16 07:22:03 vpn-gateway ipsec[2578]: 06[ENC] generating IKE_AUTH response 1 [ EF(1/3) ]
Jul 16 07:22:03 vpn-gateway ipsec[2578]: 06[ENC] generating IKE_AUTH response 1 [ EF(2/3) ]
Jul 16 07:22:03 vpn-gateway ipsec[2578]: 06[ENC] generating IKE_AUTH response 1 [ EF(3/3) ]
Jul 16 07:22:03 vpn-gateway ipsec[2578]: 06[NET] sending packet: from 10.0.0.2[4500] to x.x.x.x[6511] (1236 bytes)
Jul 16 07:22:03 vpn-gateway ipsec[2578]: 06[NET] sending packet: from 10.0.0.2[4500] to x.x.x.x[6511] (1236 bytes)
Jul 16 07:22:03 vpn-gateway ipsec[2578]: 06[NET] sending packet: from 10.0.0.2[4500] to x.x.x.x[6511] (804 bytes)
Jul 16 07:22:03 vpn-gateway ipsec[2578]: 07[NET] received packet: from x.x.x.x[6511] to 10.0.0.2[4500] (96 bytes)
Jul 16 07:22:03 vpn-gateway ipsec[2578]: 07[ENC] parsed IKE_AUTH request 2 [ EAP/RES/ID ]
Jul 16 07:22:03 vpn-gateway ipsec[2578]: 07[IKE] received EAP identity 'x'
Jul 16 07:22:03 vpn-gateway ipsec[2578]: 07[IKE] initiating EAP_MSCHAPV2 method (id 0xFF)
Jul 16 07:22:03 vpn-gateway ipsec[2578]: 07[ENC] generating IKE_AUTH response 2 [ EAP/REQ/MSCHAPV2 ]
Jul 16 07:22:03 vpn-gateway ipsec[2578]: 07[NET] sending packet: from 10.0.0.2[4500] to x.x.x.x[6511] (112 bytes)
Jul 16 07:22:03 vpn-gateway ipsec[2578]: 08[NET] received packet: from x.x.x.x[6511] to 10.0.0.2[4500] (144 bytes)
Jul 16 07:22:03 vpn-gateway ipsec[2578]: 08[ENC] parsed IKE_AUTH request 3 [ EAP/RES/MSCHAPV2 ]
Jul 16 07:22:03 vpn-gateway ipsec[2578]: 08[ENC] generating IKE_AUTH response 3 [ EAP/REQ/MSCHAPV2 ]
Jul 16 07:22:03 vpn-gateway ipsec[2578]: 08[NET] sending packet: from 10.0.0.2[4500] to x.x.x.x[6511] (144 bytes)
Jul 16 07:22:03 vpn-gateway ipsec[2578]: 05[NET] received packet: from x.x.x.x[6511] to 10.0.0.2[4500] (80 bytes)
Jul 16 07:22:03 vpn-gateway ipsec[2578]: 05[ENC] parsed IKE_AUTH request 4 [ EAP/RES/MSCHAPV2 ]
Jul 16 07:22:03 vpn-gateway ipsec[2578]: 05[IKE] EAP method EAP_MSCHAPV2 succeeded, MSK established
Jul 16 07:22:03 vpn-gateway ipsec[2578]: 05[ENC] generating IKE_AUTH response 4 [ EAP/SUCC ]
Jul 16 07:22:03 vpn-gateway ipsec[2578]: 05[NET] sending packet: from 10.0.0.2[4500] to x.x.x.x[6511] (80 bytes)
Jul 16 07:22:03 vpn-gateway charon: 06[IKE] authentication of '192.168.43.7' with EAP successful
Jul 16 07:22:03 vpn-gateway ipsec[2578]: 06[NET] received packet: from x.x.x.x[6511] to 10.0.0.2[4500] (112 bytes)
Jul 16 07:22:03 vpn-gateway charon: 06[IKE] authentication of 'CN=ipsec.xxx.xxx' (myself) with EAP
Jul 16 07:22:03 vpn-gateway charon: 06[IKE] IKE_SA AndroidCon[1] established between 10.0.0.2[CN=ipsec.xxx.xxx]...x.x.x.x[192.168.43.7]
Jul 16 07:22:03 vpn-gateway charon: 06[IKE] peer requested virtual IP %any
Jul 16 07:22:03 vpn-gateway charon: 06[IKE] assigning virtual IP 172.31.0.1 to peer 'x'
Jul 16 07:22:03 vpn-gateway charon: 06[IKE] peer requested virtual IP %any6
Jul 16 07:22:03 vpn-gateway charon: 06[IKE] no virtual IP found for %any6 requested by 'x'
Jul 16 07:22:03 vpn-gateway charon: 06[IKE] CHILD_SA AndroidCon{1} established with SPIs cd928f30_i a2493b60_o and TS 0.0.0.0/0 === 172.31.0.1/32
Jul 16 07:22:03 vpn-gateway charon: 06[ENC] generating IKE_AUTH response 5 [ AUTH CPRP(ADDR DNS DNS DNS DNS) SA TSi TSr N(MOBIKE_SUP) N(NO_ADD_ADDR) ]
Jul 16 07:22:03 vpn-gateway charon: 06[NET] sending packet: from 10.0.0.2[4500] to x.x.x.x[6511] (256 bytes)
```

A test from a connected linux client (strongswan) showed the same problematic results. Google services are not available. Not when using a webbrowser to do it, that is. The servers themselves are responding to pings:

```
root@antelope:/home/karsten# ping mail.google.com
PING googlemail.l.google.com (173.194.196.17) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from ix-in-f17.1e100.net (173.194.196.17): icmp_seq=1 ttl=51 time=377 ms
64 bytes from ix-in-f17.1e100.net (173.194.196.17): icmp_seq=2 ttl=51 time=358 ms
^C
--- googlemail.l.google.com ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 2 received, 0% packet loss, time 1000ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 358.685/367.880/377.076/9.215 ms

root@antelope:/home/karsten# ping youtube.com
PING youtube.com (173.194.196.136) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from ix-in-f136.1e100.net (173.194.196.136): icmp_seq=1 ttl=51 time=360 ms
^C
--- youtube.com ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 1 received, 50% packet loss, time 1000ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 360.711/360.711/360.711/0.000 ms
```

So I enabled logging for firefox:

```
export NSPR_LOG_MODULES="nsHttp:3,nsHostResolver:3"
export NSPR_LOG_FILE="/home/karsten/firefox.log"
```

The log is quite verbose but it doesn't tell me much about my problem. What is happening while the tunnel is established can be found here: 
["tunnel is up"](https://pastebin.com/V5DkgdDx)

When the tunnel is deactivated and all google services are accessable again it looks like this:
["tunnel is down"](https://pastebin.com/yx3fgTk5)

Gathered firefox log in a different way (via about:networking in the standard configuration). It doesn't give any better information to me but maybe someone else.

With tunnel up: [new-firefox.log-up](https://pastebin.com/n91FuBDR)
And tunnel down (google services available): [new-firefox.log-downa](https://pastebin.com/KYEAN9xD)

Meanwhile the strongswan app on Android shows the same behavior. It is working fine only for a few moments.

The "firewall" on the server:

```
root@vpn-gateway:/home/karsten# iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
root@vpn-gateway:/home/karsten# iptables -L -t nat
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             policy match dir out pol ipsec
MASQUERADE  all  --  172.31.0.0/24        anywhere            
root@vpn-gateway:/home/karsten# iptables -L -t mangle
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
TCPMSS     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             policy match dir in pol ipsec tcp flags:SYN,RST/SYN tcpmss match 1361:1536 TCPMSS set 1360
TCPMSS     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             policy match dir out pol ipsec tcp flags:SYN,RST/SYN tcpmss match 1361:1536 TCPMSS set 1360
```

Here are some handpicked entries from the pcap file generated with tcpdump.
On the responder side when tunnel is up and initiator is trying to access www.google.com: [tunnel-up.responder](https://pastebin.com/cdP6rWLb)

On the initiator side at the same time: [tunnel-up.initiator](https://pastebin.com/x6tUqwsp)

And as a reference, this is how it should look lik on the initiator. Here the tunnel is down. [tunnel-down.initiator](https://pastebin.com/16vhV9QT)

Comment: The TLSv1.2 Server Hello message from www.google.com is quite big (1470 bytes due to the certificate chain), so this might be an issue with IP fragmentation (some firewalls/routers drop IP fragments) because of the IPsec overhead (tunnel mode ESP and the UDP encapsulation will add at least as much overhead that the packet is more than 1500 bytes and probably gets fragmented). Did you try [configuring MSS clamping](https://wiki.strongswan.org/projects/strongswan/wiki/ForwardingAndSplitTunneling#MTUMSS-issues) on your server?

Comment: I did. Also tried the other suggestions from the site you mentioned. But no change.

Comment: Hm, you're probably going to have to tcpdump and sort through the packet capture.

Comment: The 1360 byte MSS you configured might still be too much in your case. In the tcpdump output you see a 1400 byte IP packet from Google (Frame 471, starting at line 739), which results in an ICMP Fragmentation Needed (Frame 472, line 808) that's sent directly by your server, i.e. even before it is encrypted and wrapped in ESP it notices that the packet would exceed the MTU.

Comment: Thank you very much. That did it. I picked 1000 byte MSS just to sure. Now I can access google services through the tunnel.

Answer (score 0):

With the help from you I could manage the problem. After adjusting the MSS down to 1350 bytes the setup works as expected.

```
root@vpn-gateway:/home/karsten# iptables -L -t mangle
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
TCPMSS     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             policy match dir in pol ipsec tcp flags:SYN,RST/SYN tcpmss match 1351:1536 TCPMSS set 1350
TCPMSS     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             policy match dir out pol ipsec tcp flags:SYN,RST/SYN tcpmss match 1351:1536 TCPMSS set 1350

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

The question for me remains why this is necessary in the first place.

Comment: Because the ICMPs sent by your server that would notify the Google servers that they should lower their path MTU don't make it there (this is just an example of [PMTUD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_MTU_Discovery) not working).

Comment: Exactly. I opened a ticket in their issue tracker. Maye we can help;D

Comment: And they closed it.